# Using redis as a session store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I'm using redis as a session store and for some other stuff too. I use gem `redis-rails` and this is how I configured it for heroku :

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :redis_store , redis_server: ENV['REDISTOGO_URL']
```

How and where do I set default ttl for all redis keys? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the parameter **expire_in**

MyApp::Application.config.session_store :redis_store , redis_server: ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'],  :expire_in  => 900

Units are in seconds